# Adicionar um DropDownListFor com o resultado do Jquery asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Quero saber como fazer isso de uma forma mais amigável possível.

Tenho uma ActionResult

```
public ActionResult IncluirProspecto()
{

    //retorna o cadastro classificação do prospecto
    var tbuscarClassificacaoProspecto = new ClassificacaoProspectoAplicacao();
    var listaClassificacao = tbuscarClassificacaoProspecto.ListarTodos();
    ViewBag.LocalClassificacao = new SelectList(listaClassificacao, "IDCLASSIFICACAOPROSPECTO", "DESCRICAO");

    //retorna a categoria do prospecto
    var tbuscarCategoriaProspecto = new CategoriaProspectoAplicacao();
    var listaCategoria = tbuscarCategoriaProspecto.ListarTodos();
    ViewBag.LocalCategoria = new SelectList(listaCategoria, "IDCATEGORIA", "DESCRICAO");



    return View();
}
```

Na view tenho:

```
<div class="col-md-3 form-group">
    @Html.Label("Classificação:")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.IDCLASSIFICACAOPROSPECTO, ViewBag.LocalClassificacao as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control", id = "ProjetoId", required = "required" })
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 form-group">
    @Html.Label("Categoria:")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.IDCATEGORIA, ViewBag.LocalCategoria as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control",  required = "required" })
</div>
```

Desta forma eu consigo trazer os dois DropDownListFor com os dados, agora, como eu posso fazer o ViewBag.LocalClassificacao busca os dados de acordo com o  ViewBag.LocalCategoria

No controller eu fiz assim:

```
public JsonResult SelecionarCategoriaProspecto(int? id)
{

    var tbuscarClassProspecto = new CategoriaProspectoAplicacao();
    var listaClassificacao = tbuscarClassProspecto.ListarPoIdClassificacao(Convert.ToInt32(id));
    return Json(listaClassificacao, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Como adicionar a resposta dentro do DropDownListFor

Comment: @Randrade, a resposta apresentada lá, não ficou muito clara, ficou prejudicado o entendimento.

Comment: A sua pergunta é a mesma. As respostas lá são as formas de se fazer o que deseja. Para isso, você precisará utilizar js para fazer isso. Caso não entenda muito de javascript, acho que nenhuma resposta poderia lhe ajudar. Aconselharia a ver os exemplos [apresentados no google](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=cascade%20dropdownlist%20asp.net%20mvc) para entender melhor. Tudo é a "mesma coisa", mas de formas diferentes. Talvez com mais exemplos você poderia entender melhor.